# How to remove buttons from CKeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor

The question is in the title : How to remove buttons from CKeditor 4 .

Documentation does not answer it clearly

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Based on reinmar answer and tested here is the better answer. Add this in your ckeditor config.js :

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,JustifyCenter';
```

For reference you can find the complete list of CKeditor 4 buttons there : 
http://ckeditor.com/comment/123266#comment-123266

Comment: Btw, for anyone else reading this and struggling, note that there must be *NO* spaces between the button names if you have multiple.

Comment: ckeditor.config.removePlugins = "forms"; when using asp.net control see more values fir csv http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Comment: I think config.removeButtons is only available in CKEditor version > 3. I can't update at this time. Just commenting for those in my position. Edit: I just noticed that the question outlines CKEditor version 4. Whops. I shouldn't scan SO pages as much as I do..

Comment: If your codebase has duplicate copies of the CKeditor code, with different configs - maybe it's obvious, but just grep for `removeButtons`. I'm mentioning it because I am maintaining a codebase where the files containing CKEditor configs aren't all named `config.js`. (From someone previously combining various sources and so on.) Also, if you don't find `removeButtons`, look for `toolbarGroups` or `toolbar` (depending on version), and start from there.

Comment: is there anyway to then add a button - if i have two CK Editors and I want the Image Button removed from one but left on the other how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 49):

I finaly found how, but I don't like this way as instead of removing what you don't want, you define which buttons you want (and simply don't put what you don't want). 
When you call CKeditor.replace you can define the toolbar like so:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'YOURE_TEXT_AREA_ID', {
    toolbar: [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
]
});
```

(For reference this is the standard full toolbar)
 Items represent buttons so simply delete the items you don't want. 
Thats it.

Is there any better answer ?

Comment: See [`config.removeButtons`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons). Buttons will be also removed if you remove entire plugins (using [`config.removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins).

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted; I used removeButtons to remove links from a minimal CK Editor instance, and it removed the link related buttons but added a load of extra buttons in for no particularly good reason, and using this technique to explicitly add the few I wanted in was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Well, if you want all the actions but a few, maybe the chosen best answer fits better. But if you need just a few actions, this is the right answer. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 18):

After much fooling around with manually removing button and styling the toolbar by editing the `config.js` file, I found the ToolBar Configurator.

With that you can easily enable or disable buttons. Change button group order and add separators.

It is located in the `/samples/toolbarconfigurator` of the `ckeditor` folder. Just launch the `index.html`. The Toolbar Configurator is inlcuded in all the different download packages on the [download page](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/)

When you are done creating your toolbar, just click `Get toolbar config` and copy the style to the `config.js` file located in the main `ckeditor` folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the most helpful answer here. I missed the part `located in the /samples/toolbarconfigurator`. Especially great, that in _Advanced Mode_, you can arrange buttons to be anywhere you'd like, at any row, at any place.

Comment: this is the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 15):

To remove buttons, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'Save,Print,Preview,Find,About,Maximize,ShowBlocks';
});
```

The comma-separated list must contain the name of each button you want to remove. The following link is the complete list of the buttons containing the toolbar ckeditor:

[list-buttons](http://s1.ckeditor.com/sites/default/files/uploads/Complete%20List%20of%20Toolbar%20Items%20for%20CKEditor.pdf)

Comment: This is working, but when I try to remove source button by adding 'source' in the above list, it do not remove source button. Any clue??

Comment: perfect example :)

Comment: Broken link....

Answer (score 14):

In config.js file inside scripts/ckeditor/ of your project, just do the following way

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,image,flash,iframe,link,smiley,tabletools,find,pagebreak,templates,about,maximize,showblocks,newpage,language';

config.removeButtons = 'Copy,Cut,Paste,Undo,Redo,Print,Form,TextField,Textarea,Button,SelectAll,NumberedList,BulletedList,CreateDiv,Table,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Select,HiddenField';
```

Comment: This is better solution.

Answer (score 9):

Open your config.js file and paste this code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'blockquote,save,flash,iframe,tabletools,pagebreak,templates,about,showblocks,newpage,language,print,div';
    config.removeButtons = 'Print,Form,TextField,Textarea,Button,CreateDiv,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Select,HiddenField,Radio,Checkbox,ImageButton,Anchor,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Font,Format,Styles,Preview,Indent,Outdent';
};
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a handy tool come by default with the bundle, which can be found at `ckeditor/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html`. It allows you to config the toolbar using GUI.

Comment: best answer. Thats what i wanted exactlyr. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its so Simple.
Modify `config.js` file as below

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

config.removePlugins = 'save,newpage,flash,about,iframe,language'; 
//The options which you don't need in the toolbar, you can add them in the above remove plugins list.

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
config.removeButtons = 'Save';
```

this will completely remove the save button.

Answer (score 0):

**The first way to solve this problem**

1. Go to `node modules -> @ckeditor -> ckeditor-build-classic -> build ->ckeditor.js`

Go or search for `defaultConfig` in `ckeditor.js` --- you will find out in the last few lines

Here remove the unwanted fields like table, media, etc

**The second way to solve the problem**

Here are the complete list:

```
defaultConfig={toolbar:{items:["heading","|","bold","italic","link","bulletedList","numberedList","|","indent","outdent","|","imageUpload","blockQuote","insertTable","mediaEmbed","undo","redo"]},image:{toolbar:["imageStyle:full","imageStyle:side","|","imageTextAlternative"]},table:{contentToolbar:["tableColumn","tableRow","mergeTableCells"]},language:"en"}}]).default}
```

Eg - remove the table from the Editor

```
defaultConfig={toolbar:{items:["heading","|","bold","italic","link","bulletedList","numberedList","|","indent","outdent","|","imageUpload","blockQuote","mediaEmbed","undo","redo"]},image:{toolbar:["imageStyle:full","imageStyle:side","|","imageTextAlternative"]},language:"en"}}]).default}
```

put in the constructor of the component.ts file

```
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig={toolbar:{items:["heading","|","bold","italic","link","bulletedList","numberedList","|","indent","outdent","|","imageUpload","blockQuote","mediaEmbed","undo","redo"]},image:{toolbar:["imageStyle:full","imageStyle:side","|","imageTextAlternative"]},language:"en"}}]).default}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own toolbars with whatever buttons you want in whatever order you want by doing this:

1. set up a bespoke toolbar

   CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MA = [
   ['Source','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','-','Undo','Redo','RemoveFormat','-','Link','Unlink','Anchor','-','Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
   '/', ['Format','Templates','Bold','Italic','Underline','-','Superscript','-',['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
   '-','NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent']
   ];

**2)select it when you create your ckeditor instance**

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'myeditor',{   toolbar:'MA' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all ckeditor buttons by using jquery.
example "      $(".ql-formats").hide();        ".use browser developer debug tool to see all class names of  buttons.to hide only specific detail buttons of ckeditor. exmaple " $(".ql-image").hide(), $(".ql-video").hide() "