# how to create simple multi line text box editor using asp tag helpers(make <br/> only with out text color and size etc )

Tags: asp.net

i want to use simple text box editor for comments using asp tag helper

i tried to use text area tag bu there isn't result

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Body" class="control-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Body"  class="control-label"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Body" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

the result of textarea it is not care about new line

Comment: You could use an editor like [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/). You can then [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48469337/5836671) the toolbox elements you want to show/hide.

Comment: thanks i used tiny text editor and configured it