# How to remove specific button from ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor on two textarea,but Problem is I need limited options to show like (B,I U ) bullet format, I followed one link and made changes in config.js,but it is reflecting on all ckediotr, butI want changes should reflect on specific ckediotr of that textarea.

link I followed:

[How to remove buttons from CKeditor 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538462/how-to-remove-buttons-from-ckeditor-4)

1) I need only B,I,U so what I have to mention in js ile

2) above bulltes style need in only one ckeditor

remove buttons / bullets  from config.js file of ckeditor.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
config.removePlugins = 'save,newpage,flash,about,iframe,language'; 
//The options which remove all styles except (B,I,U)
};



<textarea class="form-control editor_cls" id="htapply" rows="5" required></textarea>

 <textarea class="form-control editor_cls"  id="htapply" rows="5" required></textarea>
```

Script to apply ckeditor on  all textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.editor_cls').each(function() { //alert();
  var editor_id = $(this).attr('id');
  CKEDITOR.replace( editor_id, {
      height: 100
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your textareas should have different ids, you shouldn't have the same id twice in the same page. If you give them different ids you will be able to differentiate between them easily:

```html
<textarea class="form-control editor_cls" id="htapply" rows="5" required></textarea>

<textarea class="form-control editor_cls"  id="htapply2" rows="5" required></textarea>
```

Then in your JS code you can:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.editor_cls').each(function() { //alert();
  var editor_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (editor_id === 'htapply2') {
    // add B, I, U to this editor
    CKEDITOR.replace(editor_id, {
      height: 100,
      plugins: 'bold,italic,underline',
      removePlugins: 'save,newpage,flash,about,iframe,language'
    });
  } else {
    CKEDITOR.replace(editor_id, {
      height: 100,
      removePlugins: 'save,newpage,flash,about,iframe,language'
    });
  }
});
</script>
```